# Android ImageButton border color transparent but all buttons connected

Tags: android

I have a list of `ImageButton` placed vertically, and there are some space between each button with the gray border. After I set the background color to transparent or white, all buttons are connected, I mean the space that separates buttons is disappeared.

I want to ask is there any default padding or margin while using `ImageButton`, so that I can remove its background but remain its `padding` or `margin` between buttons just like default?

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/btnT"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/btnB"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/btnE"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: add a drawable to the background with contains a transparent solid and a colored strok

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this as a drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

and put it as background for the ImageButton

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also make the  android:background="@null" and remove android:cropToPadding="false" 

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it is still the same

Answer (score 0):

An Example to insert in all ImageButtons,remove the extra padding statement which will not apply to you

```
  <ImageButton

    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageButton6"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/btnE"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: Is this default `padding`? Also, the value in `dp` will be different in different screen size, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Then I suggest the marginTop,marginBottom they avoid that according to me

Answer (score 0):

btn_border XML in res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#85d1fa" />

<stroke
    android:width="2.2dp"
    android:color="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```

ImageButton on your Layout XML

```
<ImageButton

android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/imageButton6"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/btnE"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:paddingRight="30dp"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
android:paddingBottom="30dp"
android:background="@drawable/btn_border"
android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```